# What are the known ways to model baryons in string theory?

Tags: string-theory, standard-model, branes, baryons

As I understand, string theory models baryons by including a so called "baryon vertex".

Is this right?

It seems that baryon vertex's are usually D/M branes. Is that always the case?

Comment: To be sure, are you taking about string theory or e.g Lund  string model of hadronisation?

Comment: @innisfree string theory